# Finding deeply nested index path from array in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working with an array where I am trying to find the index path of an object nested 4 layers deep and would like for it to return in array format `[1, 0, 1, 0]` or string 1-1-1-1.

```js
const field = {
   id: "field-e656ba1c-2b18-4dfd-b582-03f1fbfc5642",
   type: "field",
   key: "testKey",
}


const layout = [
   {
      id: "section-766f11d4-c97c-4d5e-8dca-3bf5a2c0356e",
      type: 'section',
      children: [
         {
            id: "row-54eed1fd-0592-4196-bbff-e0befd65db41",
            type: "row",
            children: [
              {
                 id: "column-4d9844ea-19c9-454f-b2f0-17a63f6d2f1e",
                 type: "column",
                 children: [{
   id: "field-e656ba1c-2b18-4dfd-b582-03f1fbfc5642",
   type: "field",
   key: "testKeys",
}],
              },
            ],
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      id: "section-766f11d4-c97c-4d5e-8dca-3bf5a2c0356e",
      type: 'section',
      children: [
         {
            id: "row-54eed1fd-0592-4196-bbff-e0befd65db41",
            type: "row",
            children: [
              {
                 id: "column-4d9844ea-19c9-454f-b2f0-17a63f6d2f1e",
                 type: "column",
                 children: [field],
              },
            ],
         }
      ]
   }
]

          

const findIdx = (array, fieldKey) => {
   const find = (array) => {
      if (!array) return
      let inner,
          index = array.findIndex((o) => {
             if (o.key === fieldKey) return true
             if (Array.isArray(o)) return (inner = find(o))
             return (inner = find(o.children))
          })
      return index !== -1 && [index, ...(inner || [])]
   }

   return find(array)
}

console.log('path: ', findIdx(layout, 'testKey'))
```

However it returns false every time and was hoping to get another set of eyes on it to see where I'm going wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I've converted your code into a runnable snippet, but it won't work with all those `...` in it. Can you edit it to make it valid code?

Comment: Also, type annotations are TypeScript, not JavaScript.

Comment: @Barmar sorry about that... had to fix a few things with it. Should be good now

Comment: You're comparing with `o.id`, not `o.key`.

Comment: You're also never accessing the `children` of a value. And shouldn't the path be `[0, 0, 0, 0]`?

Comment: Yeah.. been looking at it way to long and updated the post with what works. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Your code never makes access to `children` keys.

Here is an implementation of `findIdx` that does that. Since your `field.id` sits in the very first *leaf*, the path will be `[0,0,0,0]` for that example:

```js
function findIdx(array, fieldKey) {
    for (let [idx, obj] of array.entries()) {
        const res = obj.id === fieldKey ? [] : findIdx(obj.children ?? [], fieldKey);
        if (res) return [idx, ...res];
    }
}

const field = {id: "field-e656ba1c-2b18-4dfd-b582-03f1fbfc5642",type: "field",key: "testKey",}
const layout = [{id: "section-766f11d4-c97c-4d5e-8dca-3bf5a2c0356e",type: 'section',children: [{id: "row-54eed1fd-0592-4196-bbff-e0befd65db41",type: "row",children: [{id: "column-4d9844ea-19c9-454f-b2f0-17a63f6d2f1e",type: "column",children: [{id: "field-e656ba1c-2b18-4dfd-b582-03f1fbfc5642",type: "field",key: "testKeys",}],},],}]},{id: "section-766f11d4-c97c-4d5e-8dca-3bf5a2c0356e",type: 'section',children: [{id: "row-54eed1fd-0592-4196-bbff-e0befd65db41",type: "row",children: [{id: "column-4d9844ea-19c9-454f-b2f0-17a63f6d2f1e",type: "column",children: [field]}]}]}]
console.log(findIdx(layout, field.id));
```